# Map entity to lookup table with composite foreign key that is partially hard-coded

Tags: entity-framework-core

Using EF Core 3.1.2 database-first, we have a model like below. This is an inherited database, and changing the schema is not preferred. We also have a team decision to prefer data annotations rather than fluent.

We have many different tables that have related rows in `ReferenceDictionary`. The relationship between these tables and `ReferenceDictionary` is defined by the composite key (`ReferenceDictionary.Category`, `ReferenceDictionary.Id`). The `Category` value is always the same for any given row in the same related table.

For example, all instances of `FooEntity` from `FooTable` use a value of `'FooCategory'` for `ReferenceDictionary.Category`. Likewise, all instances of `BarEntity` from `BarTable` use a value of `'BarCategory'` for `ReferenceDictionary.Category`.

The `Category` for `ReferenceDictionary` is not actually stored anywhere in `FooTable` or `BarTable`, however (there are no database columns `FooEntity.ReferenceDictionaryCategory` or `BarEntity.ReferenceDictionaryCategory`).

I tried the solution below using the `[NotMapped]` attribute to configure this relationship, but I get an error that `FooEntity.ReferenceDictionaryCategory` is not a column in the database (which it isn't).

**Question:**

How can I configure the EF relationships so that the navigational property `FooEntity.ReferenceDictionary` successfully maps to an instance of `ReferenceDictionary` using the following composite key mapping?

- `ReferenceDictionary.Category` = `'FooCategory'`
- `ReferenceDictionary.Id` = `FooEntity.ReferenceDictionaryId`

**Current Code:**

```cs
public class ReferenceDictionary
{
    [PrimaryKey(Order = 1)]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [PrimaryKey(Order = 2)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class FooEntity
{
    [Key]        
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string ReferenceDictionaryCategory { get; } = "FooCategory";

    public int ReferenceDictionaryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ReferenceDictionaryCategory) + ", " + nameof(ReferenceDictionaryId))]
    public virtual ReferenceDictionary ReferenceDictionary { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class BarEntity
{
    [Key]        
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string ReferenceDictionaryCategory { get; } = "BarCategory";

    public int ReferenceDictionaryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ReferenceDictionaryCategory) + ", " + nameof(ReferenceDictionaryId))]
    public virtual ReferenceDictionary ReferenceDictionary { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried to understand your model, but i am sorry, it is really messy. Narrow down your question to two tables and mentioned relationships properly

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @cdev . I just re-worded the question a bit. Maybe this is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set foreign key like this

```
[ForeignKey("ReferenceDictionaryCategory,ReferenceDictionaryId")]
public virtual ReferenceDictionary ReferenceDictionary { get; set; }
```

and after you try to load data like below,

```
var test = await _dbcontext.FooEntities.Include(x => x.ReferenceDictionary).ToListAsync();
```

It will translate to sql like below,

```
SELECT  [x].[Id], 
        [x].[ReferenceDictionaryCategory], 
        [x].[ReferenceDictionaryId], 
        [x.ReferenceDictionary].[Category], 
        [x.ReferenceDictionary].[Id]
FROM [FooEntity] AS [x]
LEFT JOIN [ReferenceDictionary] AS [x.ReferenceDictionary] 
ON ([x].[ReferenceDictionaryCategory] = [x.ReferenceDictionary].[Category]) 
    AND ([x].[ReferenceDictionaryId] = [x.ReferenceDictionary].[Id])
```

That is why you are getting `[ReferenceDictionaryCategory]` is not a column. It does not do any effect by adding `[NotMapped]` cause it is not the place for calling column.

There is a workaround, you can write query like below. (If you don't want to add `ReferenceDictionaryCategory` column to `FooEntity`)

```
var result = from fe in _dbcontext.FooEntities
             join rd in _dbcontext.ReferenceDictionaries
             on new { Category = "FooCategory", fe.Id } equals new { rd.Category, rd.Id } into data
             from final in data.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new FooEntity
             {
                 Id = fe.Id,
                 ReferenceDictionaryId = fe.ReferenceDictionaryId,
                 ReferenceDictionary = final
             };
```

This will generate sql like this.

```
SELECT [rd].[Category], [rd].[Id], [fe].[Id] AS [Id0], [fe].[ReferenceDictionaryId]
FROM [FooEntity] AS [fe]
LEFT JOIN [ReferenceDictionary] AS [rd] ON (N'FooCategory' = [rd].[Category]) AND ([fe].[Id] = [rd].[
```

Comment: This is a good tip. I was hoping there was some EF hack I could use to still use a navigational property, but not sure if that's possible. Will keep this open for a bit to see if anyone else has an idea, but this solution will work, albeit not as elegant as I had hoped. Thanks!